# C++ variable type selection depending on switch

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to implement something like the following:

```
int x = <random integer in range [0,3]>;
<some declaration of T>

switch (x) {
  case 0:
    T = int;    
    break;

  case 1:
    T = double;
    break;

  case 2:
    T = short;
    break;

  case 3:
    T = char;
    break;

  default:
    T = long long;
    break;
}

// type of y is dependent on whatever T resolved to in switch
T y;
```

So I'm aware of std::conditional but the shortcoming there is that the type is dependent on a predicate which as a boolean output. I was curious if there is a standard/best practice for this situation? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What's the bigger picture? Why are you trying to do this? Chances are there's a better way.

Comment: Most probably you are taking wrong approach to your problem

Comment: You could create a function template that does whatever you need to with `y` and then instantiate the template with different types based on the switch statement. There's probably a better way to do whatever you're attempting, but it's hard to say without a more realistic example.

Comment: I am writing a generator for a test -- the DUT has to be able to handle variable (custom) types (not put in this example for simplicity's sake) which are defined in C/C++. For my noise generator I am doing almost exactly what I've put in the explanation above -- come up with a random number, depending on that random number instantiate a new object whose type is dependent on the random number.

Comment: @user1373317 why not simply use _templates_ here? It sounds like it's what you need.

Comment: @Pawel, there's such a large number of types that I was curious if there was a method of doing what I wanted that didn't have the memory footprint overhead of implementing templates.

Comment: @user1373317 If you're looking for a more memory efficient method, use `void*`. Be aware tho it's not as safe, nor as readable as using templates.

Answer (score 1):

Types are a compile time construct.  If you need to be able to switch on them at run time, you need to a discriminated union such as [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this.
Types have to be determined compile time.
C++ is stricktly typed.
The only way to relax this rule is polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a `union`, perhaps you want to revisit your design....